# Behaviour of explicit copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17, copy-constructor

I have the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  A(int x=1, int y=1) : x(x), y(y) { }
  A(const A& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y) { }

  operator bool() const { return !x && !y; }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& a) {
    os << a.x << "," << a.y << "\n";
    return os;
  }

  int x;
  int y;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  A const A10x10(10, 10);
  A a;
  std::cout << a;
  A aa = A10x10;
  std::cout << aa;
  return 0;
}
```

The above prints:

```
1,1
10,10
```

When i change the copy constructor to explicit (i.e. `explicit A(const A& other);`) i am getting:

```
1,1
0,1
```

I put a print statement inside the (explicit) copy constructor and indeed it is not being called. Why is this happening? What difference does the `explicit` make?

I am using C++17, compiling with Clang10.

Comment: Is this a typo `A::A() : x(x), y(y) {}` (missing parameters) ?  if not you have UB.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? If if you made the copy constructor explicit, your code should fail to compile... not just not get called or do something else.

Comment: This code doesn't [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/qvjqPh). Please make a [mre]

Comment: You are right. I ommited an important bit (the bool overload) and with that bit i think i kind-of see it. But i am not exactly sure whats happening. I have updated the question with an MRCP.

Comment: Actually, I'm seeing the opposite. `10,10` when implicit, and `0,1` when explicit.

Comment: Change (or add an `aaa` version) the line `A aa = A::A10x10;` to `bool temp = A::A10x10; A aa = temp;`  Now do you understand?

Comment: @cigien Im sorry i messed up the phrasing. Have a read again again please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

> ```
> A aa = A10x10;
> ```

Performs copy initialization. Copy initialization works by converting the object to the type of the object being initialized. However, copy initialization does this by implicit conversion. And implicit conversion *cannot* call an `explicit` constructor.

Even if it's the copy constructor.

Now by all rights, you'd think you would get a compile error. But you don't. Why? Because `A` is implicitly convertible by user-defined conversion to `bool`. And `bool` is convertible by standard conversion to `int`. And `A` can in fact be constructed from a single value of type `int`. And while implicit conversion allows only one user-defined conversion, it does allow a user-defined conversion followed by a standard conversion.

So that's what happens. It's why the first value in `aa` is 0 when the copy constructor is `explicit`.

Generally speaking, *always* make `operator bool` `explicit`. And *never* make the copy constructor `explicit`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Its very clear. I have a follow up question if you don't mind. Say, i overloaded `operator int` as well, would that one be picked instead of `operator bool`? And if so is that because an int conversion is closer to the type of the `A(int, int)` constructor than the bool conversion?